# The output of my code comes as a different alphabet in every line

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

```
message =input("Type message ")
shift = int(input("Enter number to code "))
message = message.lower()
print (message)


for a in message:        
  if a in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" :
      number = ord(a)
      number += shift
      if number > ord("z") :
        number -= 26
      elif number < ord("a") :
       number += 26
     message = chr(number)
   print (message)
```

above is my code to encrypt normal text to Caesar cipher on python but the outcome of the code comes out as a different alphabet in every line.

im new to coding so any kind of help or resources that you think will help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. You are also replacing `message` with the last encrypted character each loop, rather than accumulating the encrypted characters.

Comment: can you plz fix the code for me and post it as I'm new to programming

Comment: If you're new to programming, you should really learn to *fix your own code*.

Comment: any hint on where should i fix because i honestly don't understand it

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the indentation and concatenate the coded letter everytime you go through your message

You are reading your message here. If you are using Python 2.7, you should use "row_input"

```
message = raw_input("Type message ")
```

If you are using Python 3

```
message = input("Type message ")
```

The same here, but your are casting what you read to be an integer

```
shift = int(raw_input("Enter number to code "))
```

You are converting the string to be lower case

```
message = message.lower()
```

you are printing your message

```
print (message)
```

You are looping in the message, every charachter in the message is tested

> ```
> for a in list(message):
> ```

- If the charachter is an alphabet

> ```
>   if a in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" :
> ```

- we are getting [code Ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of an alphabet

> ```
> number = ord(a) 
> number += shift
> ```

- we are shifting the alphabet's ascii number to generate another letter from it later. we should limitate the number to be in the interval

> ```
> if number > ord("z") :
>   number -= 26
> elif number < ord("a") :
>   number += 26
> ```

- We generate the alphabet from the number based on ascii coding, and concatenate it with the rest of charachters

> ```
> m += chr(number)
> print "Coded message:",m
> ```

Your function should look like:

```
message = input("Type message ")
shift = int(input("Enter number to code "))
message = message.lower()
print (message)
m=''

for a in message:        
  if a in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" :
    number = ord(a)
    number += shift
    if number > ord("z") :
      number -= 26
    elif number < ord("a") :
      number += 26
    m += chr(number)
      #message = chr(number)

print("The encoded message:",m)
```

Comment: great explanation but this should not work, since you have to concatinate `m´ with at least an empty string. and you don't use python 3.x where print is a function call and not a statement anymore.

Comment: +1! thanks for your explanation. I don't use Python 3. ! I am not aware of this sensitive diff.

Answer (score 0):

Your version does not work because in `message = chr(number)`, you overwrite your output with a single "encrypted" character.

But even when you fix this, there are some issues with your code:
the if / else + - thing for example would be better written using the `modulo` operator `%`.

You also do not need to hardcode the alphabet, it's present in the `string` module. And finally: python's strings have `translate` methods, so you might want to use them:

```
import string
message =input("Type message ").lower()
shift = int(input("Enter number to code "))

encrypted = message.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase,
    string.ascii_lowercase[shift:]+string.ascii_lowercase[:shift]))
print(encrypted)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is my first year of computer science coding and i have not learned the level of advanced coding yet so i'm trying to keep my practice work simple. but i will pay attention to what you have said and will research it and probably try that in my next code.      thanks...

Answer (score 0):

properly formatted and working, i have created the same code for my CA as well

```
message =input("Type message ")
shift = int(input("Enter number to code "))
message = message.lower()
print (message)


for a in message:        
    if a in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" :
        number = ord(a)
        number += shift
        if number > ord("z") :
            number -= 26
        elif number < ord("a") :
            number += 26
    message = chr(number)
    print (message)
```